# initializing one of the parameters per each of the simulation run in anylogic

Tags: parameters, initialization, anylogic

In an anylogic project, I have an array of parameters and I want to initialized one of them to 1 per each run of simulation (others are initialized to 0). In fact I need N runs of simulation that in each only one of my parameters is initialized to 1.
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you'd want that?

Comment: @Benjamin: In my project, I have N stock and there should be a flow between each of the stocks. In other word I have N stock and N(N-1)/2 flows. In every run, I want to initialized just one the stock with a parameter and then start my simulation. as a result of each run I save a parameter. I want to initialize each stock in a separate run and the compare the results of the final parameters of each run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: create just 1 parameter `myParam`on Main and pass the current iteration number from the experiment to the Main using `getCurrentIteration()` in the experiment properties for defining `myParam`.

In the stocks, you can write some code to only turn them "on" if they match what myParam dictates, like below for stock #3:

```
if (myParam==3) {
    work}
```

If that parameter should actually hold a value to define the stocks, you could change its type to a LinkedHashMap where the key is the iteration and the value is the value for the stock.